# Access 2013 SQL query null handling

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have two SQL Server tables linked in Access. They are both joined in a simple Access query.

```
SELECT * From TableMain
LEFT JOIN TableJoin on TableMain.ID=TableJoin.ID
WHERE TableMain.ID Is Not Null AND (TableJoin.Category='Category1' OR TableJoin.Category Is Null);
```

I'm having trouble retrieving the rows where TableJoin.Category is null. I've tried `Is Null` and `<>Null`. `Is Null` works using the same two tables in SQL server, and according to [the Microsoft help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd) it should also work in Access. What am I missing?

Comment: The ODBC driver might be pulling the category field through as a zero length string instead of a null.  Perhaps try something like:  Len(Nz(TableJoin.Category,"")) = 0 or something along those lines?

Comment: try nz(TableJoin.Category='Category1')='Category1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways to check if a value is null:

- IsNull(TableJoin.Category)
- MainTable.ID Is Null
- Len(Nz(TableJoin.Category,""))=0 (credit to Fink's answer above)

Likewise (for the convenience of future readers), to check if a value is NOT null:

- Not IsNull(TableJoin.Category)
- MainTable.ID Is Not Null
- Len(Nz(TableJoin.Category,""))<>0